# Advice on creating a custom gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to create an order form for my ASP.net page (I included an example image below).  However I don't know how to approach this.  I'm assuming the best method would be a gridview but it would involve two levels of grouping.  Other requirements would be be to accept a quantity and then calculate the total price.  Can anyone point me to some good books or websites that explain creating custom grid views like this (or maybe a better method than using gridview, I'm open to whatever).

I consider myself to be an intermediate programmer in asp.net.  I understand a lot of the concepts but I'm trying to learn more practical ways of doing things.  Thanks for any knowledge you can provide!

[image]

Comment: +1 for the screenshot as clarification, also interested in the answer for this one. Though I think it'll be easier to use 2 gridviews instead.

Comment: Mario, aside from legacy apps, a GridView would not normally be chosen over a ListView which produces clean markup an no extra cost.

Comment: I'm liking IrishChieftain's recommendation right now.  I've been reading about ListViews since his comment and think it's the way I should go.  Check out this link for a nested listview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500643.aspx  Half way down the page you'll see a screen shot of something kind of simular.  I'm gonna ready some more tonight.  Thanks IC.  I'll leave this thread open for a little longer and see if anyone else has some comments we can gain from as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ListView, for two reasons:

1. It will produce clean markup
2. Using templates will give you the layout you desire

Here's an example of the type of layout you are after and how to achieve it:

[ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)

Comment: I found a really good example that gets me close to my solution.  Thanks for leading me in the right direction.  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx